# How much physics is an average person with undergraduate degree supposed to understand?

Tags: soft-question, education

Perhaps this is not the best place to ask this but I'll ask anyway.
In less than a year, I'll be getting my bachelor's in general physics from Afghanistan, however I feel like my knowledge is like a house of cards, it seems pretty from afar but slight wind might blow it all away.
What I mean is that while we have worked through some classic texts in multiple fields, we didn't finish most of the books. For example, from foundations of E.M Theory by John Reitz, we only did the first few chapters on electrostatic only.
Although I've tried to work through a lot of stuff on my own (especially mathematics), I feel like I'm just pretending I know this stuff without actually knowing much.
I feel like the depth of my understanding is really shallow.
Is this normal for undergraduates in other countries?

Comment: This is normal for humans in general (it is called the "impostor syndrome"). But in academia we feel it more strongly because there is obviously much we do not know and maybe should know... even when we are pretty senior. That you are working to shore up the house of cards is a good sign - keep on doing it!

Comment: I appreciate your guts. As most of engineers in my country just pretend that they know everything related to their curriculum

Comment: At least as important as what you know (perhaps even more important), is your willingness to tackle problems with integrity and with hard work. No one knows everything, and working with physics is a lifelong process of learning and improving. It sounds to me like you are on the right path.

Comment: *we only did the first few chapters on electrostatic only* This seems like a problem to me. You probably have a good understanding of electrostatics but not the rest of electromagnetism. If you try to read the later chapters on your own, can you understand them? I encourage further self-study. This site can be a useful resource when you have conceptual problems.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I feel much better now. Although I may not know much, I can still try to learn, plus there's even more to learn I guess (since I don't know a whole lot). You are write Mr. Smith, I did try to self study some subjects I thought are more necessary (and fun) including EMT, I'll keep trying then. Thanks everyone.